# Using float numbers as literals

Tags: floating-point, abap

I try to use float numbers to case - endcase, but dot is problem. For example

```
CASE constant.
  WHEN 3.14.   "<=============== after 3, problem.
    WRITE  / 'That's a pi'.
ENDCASE.
```

How can I solve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some quote before and after the value. The '.' will not be taken as the end of code delimiter.

```
WHEN '3.14'.
```

regards

Comment: if you consider this as the solution, could you mark my response as such ? regards

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend you create a constant rather, the solution of '3.14', while correct, will do a string conversion to a float every time it is evaluated.

```
CONSTANTS: c_pi TYPE f VALUE '3.14'. " conversion is done here, may not work on old releases

CASE constant.
  WHEN c_pi.
    WRITE/ 'That's a pi'.
```